# readdir looping more times than number of files present in the directory

Tags: c, readdir

My goal is to count the number of files in a directory. After searching around, I found a piece of code which iterates over each file in a directory. But the issue is that it's looping extra times, 2 times extra to be more precise.

So for

```
int main(void)
{   
  DIR           *d;
  struct dirent *dir;  
  char *ary[10000];
  char fullpath[256];  
  d = opendir("D:\\frames\\");
  if (d)
  {    
   int count = 1;
    while ((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL)
    {  
       snprintf(fullpath, sizeof(fullpath), "%s%d%s", "D:\\frames\\", count, ".jpg");
       int fs = fsize(fullpath);
       printf("%s\t%d\n", fullpath, fs); // using this line just for output purposes
      count++;      
    }      
    closedir(d);
  }
  getchar();
  return(0);
}
```

My folder contains 500 files, but the output is shown till 502[image]

#### UPDATE

I modified the code to read as

```
struct stat buf;
if ( S_ISREG(buf.st_mode) ) // <-- I'm assuming this says "if it is a file"
{
  snprintf(fullpath, sizeof(fullpath), "%s%d%s", "D:\\frames\\", count, ".jpg");
  int fs = fsize(fullpath);
  printf("%s\t%d\n", fullpath, fs);
}
```

But I'm getting `storage size of "buf" isn't known`. I also tried doing `struct stat buf[100]`, but that didn't help either.

Comment: It's the `.` and `..` directories. You should check the `d_type` member of the `dirent` structure to make sure you have a regular file.

Comment: You are not throwing out directories, of which here are two implicitly within each folder: "." and "..". These should be tested and ignored. Since all you care about is files, I would advise you test to see if object *is* a regular file, and if it isn't, ignore it (which will address this problem and another one you don't even know you have yet).

Comment: Yes. That's correct. When I try to print out the filenames using the object, I'm getting two extra iterations for `.` and `..`. Let me see how I can tell the script to ignore them.

Comment: Using `dir->d_type` doesn't seem to work. I'm getting `structure has no member named d_type` error.

Comment: on a linux-system, the man page says this: unsigned char  d_type;      /* type of file; not supported by all file system types */

Comment: I'm on windows. I seem to have another function known as `stat()` I'm trying that option right now

Comment: On windows it's `struct _stat` ... - mind the underscore.

Comment: `_stat` isn't working too

Comment: Did you include the necessary headers?

Comment: I've `conio`, `dirent`, and `stdio` included...are those sufficient?

Comment: Yes C...I tagged the question C, right? Or did I miss something?

Comment: Ahok, it's windows, yes, so `<conio.h>` is propably ok. For `_stat()` you need to include `<sys/types.h>`and `<sys/stat.h>`.

Comment: Argh! Apparently, the system can't find `<system/stat.h>` files. It says `no such file or directory`

Comment: Rather than guessing at the name (from the count) why not just get the actual name of the file from the `dir` variable?

Comment: That's because I want the files to be listed in ascending order. If I go by file names by using `dir->d_name`, the order is coming up like `1.jpg, 100.jpg, 101.jpg.....2.jpg, 200.jpg...`

Comment: It's `<sys/stat.h>`, not `<system/stat.h>`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in comments, you're also getting the two directories named `.` and `..`, which skews your count.

In Linux, you can use the `d_type` field of the `struct dirent` to filter them out, but the documentation says:

> The only fields in the dirent structure that are mandated by POSIX.1 are: `d_name[]`, of unspecified size, with at most `NAME_MAX` characters preceding the terminating null byte; and (as an XSI extension) `d_ino`. The other fields are unstandardized, and not present on all systems; see NOTES below for some further details.

So, assuming you're on Windows you probably don't have `d_type`. Then you can use some other call instead, for instance [`stat()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14h5k7ff%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). You can of course filter out based on name too, but if you want to skip directories anyway that is a more robust and general solution.

Comment: I'm indeed on windows. And I did find something related to `stat()`. Could you please check my updated answer (will make changes after posting this comment) and see what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `_stat()`/`stat()` on the file name you want info for.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

#ifdef WINDOWS
#  define STAT _stat
#else
#  define STAT stat
#endif

...

char * filename = ... /* let it point to some file's name */

struct STAT buffer = {0};
if (STAT(filename, &buffer)
  ... /* error */
else
{
  if (S_ISREG(buffer.st_mode))
  {
    ... /* getting here, means `filename` referrs to a ordinary file */
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you put this in terms of the code I supplied?